# Указатель не указывает, или почему появляются левые цифры

Tags: c, указатели, дерево

При добавлении элемента в дерево почему-то не заносятся данные

Вот функции для работы с деревом:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// НАСТРОЙКИ
////////////////////////////////////////////////
unsigned short int StringLength = 256; // Длина строки
unsigned short start_init = 4;        // Кол-во инициируемых элементов по умолчанию
float step_init = 1.5;                // Кол-во эл-ов добавляемых в дин. массив за раз


 // Структуры
struct incmd {
    char cmdindex;                      // Сама комманда
    char *cmdword;                      // Текстовый параметр
    unsigned long long int *cmdint;     // Числовой параметр
};

struct avlleaf { // структура для представления узлов дерева
    char key[256];                                // Ключ
    unsigned long long int llupar;                // Числовой параметр
    long long int height;                         // Высота
    struct avlleaf* left;                        // Левый ребенок
    struct avlleaf* right;                       // Правый ребенок
};

// Основные Функции (сигнатуры)
char InputFiller(struct incmd**); //Функция для заполнения массива
char TreeShell(struct incmd**);   //Функция для выполнения комманд

////////////////////////////////////////////
//     ФУНКЦИИ РАБОТЫ С АВЛ - ДЕРЕВОМ     //
////////////////////////////////////////////

// Освобождение памяти
void MakeEmpty(struct avlleaf* tree){
 if(tree == NULL) return;
 MakeEmpty(tree->left);
 MakeEmpty(tree->right);
 free(tree);
}

// Вычисление высоты
long long int Height(struct avlleaf* tree){
 if (tree == NULL) {
     return -1;
 }else {
     return tree->height;
 }
}

// Вычисление максимального элемента
long long int MaxLL(long long int a, long long int b){
 if (a > b) {
     return a;
 } else {
     return b;
 }
}

// Small Right Rotation
struct avlleaf* SRR(struct avlleaf* tree) {
 struct avlleaf* tmp;
 tmp = tree->left;
 tree->left = tmp->right;
 tmp->right = tree;
 tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;
 tmp->height =  MaxLL(Height(tmp->left), tree->height)+1;
 return tmp;
}

// Small Left Rotation
struct avlleaf* SLR(struct avlleaf* tree){
 struct avlleaf* tmp;
 tmp = tree->right;
 tree->right = tmp->left;
 tmp->left = tree;
 tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;
 tmp->height =  MaxLL(Height(tree->right), tree->height)+1 ;
 return tmp;
}

// Full Left Rotation
struct avlleaf* FLR(struct avlleaf* tree){
 tree->right = SRR(tree->right);
 return SLR(tree);
}

// Full Metal Alchemist
struct avlleaf* FRR(struct avlleaf* tree){
 tree->left = SLR(tree->left);
 return SRR(tree);
}

// Добавление листа
struct avlleaf* InsertLeaf(struct avlleaf* tree, char key[256], unsigned long long int llupar){
  unsigned short int i;
    if (tree == NULL) {
       tree         = malloc(sizeof(struct avlleaf));
       tree->llupar = llupar;
       tree->height = 0;
       tree->left   = NULL;
       tree->right  = NULL;
       for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        tree->key[i]   = key[i];
       }
    } else
    if (strcmp(key, tree->key) < 0) {
       tree->left = InsertLeaf(tree->left, key,  llupar);
       if ((Height(tree->left)) - (Height(tree->right)) == 2){
           if (strcmp(key, tree->left->key) < 0) tree = SRR(tree);
           else tree = FRR(tree);
       }
    } else
    if (strcmp(key, tree->key) > 0) {
       tree->right = InsertLeaf(tree->right, key, llupar);
       if ((Height(tree->right)) - (Height(tree->left)) == 2){
           if (strcmp(key, tree->right->key) > 0) tree = SLR(tree);
           else tree = FLR(tree);
       }
    }
    tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;
    return tree;
}

// Поиск минимального листа
struct avlleaf* FindMinL(struct avlleaf* tree){
 if(tree == NULL) return NULL;
 else if(tree->left == NULL) return tree;
 else return FindMinL(tree->left);
}

// Поиск максимального листа
struct avlleaf* FindMaxL(struct avlleaf* tree) {
 if(tree == NULL) return NULL;
 else if(tree->right == NULL) return tree;
 else return FindMaxL(tree->right);
}

// Удаление листа из дерева
struct avlleaf* DeleteLeaf(struct avlleaf* tree, char key[256]){
  struct avlleaf* temp;
  unsigned short int i;

  // Нет совпадений
  if (tree == NULL) return NULL;

  // Поиск элемента
  if (strcmp(key, tree->key) < 0) tree->left = DeleteLeaf(tree->left, key);
  else if (strcmp(key, tree->key) > 0) tree->right = DeleteLeaf(tree->right, key);

  // Иначе элемент найден - обрабатываем случаи
  // Многодетный элемент
  else if((tree->left != NULL) && (tree->right != NULL)){
    temp = FindMinL(tree->right);
    tree->llupar = temp->llupar;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        tree->key[i]   = temp->key[i];
    }
    tree->right = DeleteLeaf(tree->right, tree->key);
  }
  // Один ребенок (2й - нулловый)
  else {
    temp = tree;
    if(tree->left == NULL)    tree = tree->right;
    else if(tree->right == NULL) tree = tree->left;
    free(temp);
  }

  // Если tree стул нуловым - выходим (все ок)
  if(tree == NULL) return tree;

  // Иначе...
  tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;

  // Проверка на нарушение баланса
  // Если удалили левый узел
  if(Height(tree->left) - Height(tree->right) == 2){
            if(Height(tree->left->left) - Height(tree->left->right) == 1)
                return SLR(tree);
            else
                return FLR(tree);
  }
  // Если удалили правый узел
  else if(Height(tree->right) - Height(tree->left) == 2){
            if(Height(tree->right->right) - Height(tree->right->left) == 1)
                return SRR(tree);
            else
                return FRR(tree);
  }

  // Итог
  return tree;
}

// Получить баланс
int GetBalance(struct avlleaf* tree){
        if (tree == NULL) return 0;
        else return Height(tree->left) - Height(tree->right);
}
```

И вот работа с ним:

```
char TreeShell(struct incmd **incmd_dynmass) {

 // Переменные
 unsigned long long int tmp1_ull, tmp2_ull; // Временные переменные
 char tmpkey[256];
 struct avlleaf *tree = NULL;


 //Цикл прхода по коммандам
 for (tmp1_ull = 1; tmp1_ull <= ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]; tmp1_ull++) {
   //Проходимся по коммандам
    switch ((*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdindex) {
     case 1:

     // Ввод ключа
      for (tmp2_ull = 0; tmp2_ull < StringLength; tmp2_ull++) {
        tmpkey[tmp2_ull] = ((*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdword[tmp2_ull]);
      }

      // Создаем ключ
      tree = InsertLeaf(tree, tmpkey, (*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdint[0]);
      printf("%s", tree->key);
      printf("\n");
    }
 }
 //PrintMe(tree, 0);
 return 0;
}
```

В итоге имеем, что *printf("%s", tree->key);* пишет левые данные...

Как можно устранить эту проблему?

[Вот весь код.](https://pastebin.com/ySwdWRFG)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы все время залезаете за границу массива:

```
char key[256];
```

и

```
for (i = 0; i <= 256; i++) {
```

Comment: Спасибо - не заметил

Comment: Но нет - не помогло

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG должно помочь

Answer (score 0):

1) Нет смысла использовать

> printf("%s", tree->key);

Т.к. Вы хоть в коде пытались разобраться?
tree содержит ссылку на ПЕРВЫЙ элемент

2) У вас, как товарищ @Igor заметил, пишет в соседнюю ячейку (переполнение массива)

3) У вас сравнение строк идет через strcmp - он работает весьма специфично ([ТЫК](http://all-ht.ru/inf/prog/c/func/strcmp.html))

P.S. А вообще у нас тут Ванг нет - пишите подробней свой вопрос, мы же не можем залезть к вам в голову и понять - Что вы находите "странным поведением". (это машина - что сказали, то выполняет - БЕЗ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЙ!!!).

P.P.S. Прочтите правила форума, прежде чем задавать вопрос без вопроса. Нехорошо так писать.

Comment: Мдя... Этот же вопрос я сам задал....

Comment: У вас раздвоение личности?

Comment: @zed нет, просто я забыл про этот вопрос
А поле ответил, не смотря на автора

Comment: Вторая ночь без сна была